# Is there any reason why c blocks always have the { directly after the ^ and not on a new line?

Tags: c, coding-style, objective-c-blocks

My coding style is to always put an opening brace on a new line:

```
int aBoringCFunction()
{
    ...
```

Apple used to follow this style but changed to have the `{` on the same line as the function. When using blocks Apple code always has the `{` directly after the `^`:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                   ...
```

Is there any reason why using my style with blocks would be problematic? For example:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
{
    ...
```

I prefer my style but if it causes problems with blocks then I will have to reconsider it.

### Clarification

This question is regarding the [Blocks extension to the C language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_%28C_language_extension%29). It is not a general question about braces. The questions is whether the Blocks extension has any ramifications on code style.

Comment: This is not C, but Objective-C. Completely different language.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: No, blocks are an extension to the C language. Objective-C is a strict super set of C, therefore any additions to C, such as blocks, are applicable to Objective-C as well. Grand Central Dispatch is a C library, not an Objective-C library.

Comment: Please note that my question is specifically about C blocks and their relationship to braces. This is not a general question about braces!

Comment: @BenedictCohen: No, a "block" in C is a bunch of code surrounded by braces. Common examples include the blocks that follow your `if` and `while` statements.

Comment: @BenedictCohen: And `^` is not valid in this context in C, so it's not a C question.

Comment: @ Tomalak Geret'kal: `^` is the syntax for a C block. Please read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_(C_language_extension) before commenting further.

Comment: This is objective-c. Why do you keep changing the tags to C? The syntax `-(id)a...` clearly is objective-C and the function name is "aBoringObjectiveCFunction" .... Edit: I removed the obj-c function, so it's clean extended C code.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub: The question is relating to the Blocks extension to the C language. Yes, there is an Objective-C sample in the question, but the question as a whole relates to the Blocks extension. The Objective-C sample been removed as it is confusing people who are unfamiliar with the technologies that this question relates to.

Comment: @BenedictCohen: Please realise that some random extension to the C language is not C, before commenting further. If it's not an Objective-C question then there should be no Objective-C in the question. A "block" in C is well-defined, and I described it above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both styles are perfectly correct; it's a matter of style and preference. The only way it will be *problematic* is that you might be expected to adhere to Apple's convention depending on who your code is for. Hence you might have to go back and change the formatting slightly before your work is accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I think the block samples are mimicking Apple's standard, that's all. You can put your braces wherever you like. Suggest a thought about switching since samples online are likely to follow Apple. And it works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the style-related things that people have argued the most about, and at the same time one that matters the least.

Having the brace on the same line is the "K&R" style, the style that was used in C from the very beginning. Having it on a separate line is perhaps the most common nowadays.

But there is no evidence that one of the two styles are better than the other for clarity. If someone argues over one style over the other, ask then for scientific research on the matter. I have yet to see such.

The only thing that's important is that the code style is consistent throughout your programs. If working as a programmer in a team, the whole team should be using the same style.

Comment: Kibitz: even in "K&R" style, the opening brace *of a function definition* is often put on its own line.  I imagine this is because back in the days of K and R, function parameter declarations went in between the close parenthesis and the open brace, so it looked tidier that way.

Answer (score 0):

The c complier doesn't care where you put your braces.  Its style I personal hate [K&R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#K.26R_style) style but what really matters is the coding standards where you write your code.  If its just for personal use do whatever makes the code more readable for you.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally programmers have tried to use as few lines as possible because you can only see 24 at a time on the terminals that were being used.  Putting the { on its own line just wasted screen space.

Nowadays with large high resolution monitors I think this is less of an issue and I, like you, put the braces on their own line for neatness.

Answer (score 0):

Different people have very different coding tastes.  In general, larger projects come with coding style guidelines.  KDE, for example, likes it like you do: the { on the next line.  They also like spaces in if statements:

if ( this_var > 42 )

Which personally I don't see the need for.  I had a co-worker once that liked to have 5 blank lines after every function.  For him the visual separation was important.  For me, however, I like to get as much on the screen at once as I can.

There is no wrong.  There is only white-space.

My most favorite commit-log I ever wrote for a project after we agreed on a common style (that has now lasted for coming up on 10 years):

```
2002-04-20 00:07  hardaker

   * everything:

   White space, oh glorious white space.
   How great our though?
   The code is fine.
   We agree on functionality easily.
   What really troubles us?
   Something we can't see.
   Something between the code.
   We bow down to your magnificence,
   For you are everywhere,
   Between everything.
   Pretty nothingness you are.
```